# Visual Webpart Custom Property filled for the first time

Tags: c#, web-parts, custom-properties, customproperty

I have a webpart with two custom properties: path to a folder and name of parent node.

I want the page only to reload if one of these properties changes. If there is no change of the properties I want to expand and populate the folder structure of the selected folder (in a tree node) and display files of selected folder in the gridview beside.

Everything works fine, but if I insert the webpart for the first time, it only loads the treeview after I have changed the path in the custom property for the first time - not when inserting it for the first time.

This is because I want only reload the page if the property changes. AND when the property is filled for the first time. But how can I find out, that the property is filled for the first time? Tried with a value in a hidden field, as Viewstate or simple property of the webpart.